# Safari crashes when I open it

Tags: macos, safari, crash

After restarting my MacBook, I want to open Safari.
Safari asks me if I want re-open my windows or just restart Safari.

Whatever I do, Safari crashes and i can't open it.

I have tried to create a new session in my MacBook, and in this session Safari works.

I've been looking for the "com.apple.safari.plist" file but i can not find it...

I have checked and repaired my partitions in Disk Utility and tried to clean everything with Onyx, but nothing works.

My Macbook Pro is running on MacOS 10.10.5 version.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Launch Safari with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> held down. This is a kind of Safari "Safe Mode."

If that works you can then clear caches, change home pages and delete extensions.